What is the best combination of controllers for email parsing and user registration in jMeter
I have a jMeter project that consists of the following functions:

Generation of credentials (Email, password) (JSR223 Sampler)
Sending credentials in the HTTP request
10Sec constant timer (The timer is necessary for the code to arrive in time to the email)
Parcing a code from an email (JSR223 Sampler)
Sending the code in the HTTP request

The email in point 1) is generated according to the template "myEmail+randomString@gmail.com"
The problem is that with a high speed of sending requests, the wrong code sent to another email is displayed in point 3. I suspect that this happens due to an artificial delay of 10 seconds, so that the code has time to arrive on the email.
I don't understand what timers or logic controllers should be used to fine-tune the project to avoid the described problem. I tried using the constant througput timer in various places, but it did not give the desired result but for some reason it had no effect and the requests were sent as if it didn't exist. Can you suggest the best combination of timers and loop controllers for this?

The main problem is that you're sending emails from different virtual users to the same email address.

The "best" solution would be using different email address for different users

Alternative option would be amending your email template to contain current virtual user number and iteration if you have more than one iteration. It can be done in Groovy using ctx.getThreadNum() and vars.getIteration() correspondingly. See Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy article for more information on what do these ctx and vars guys mean.
Once done you can look up the message for this or that virtual user via RecipientTerm



I cant use different email address, but I will try the second option, thank!
